# Where is Rsyslog programname set?

Tags: logs, aws, rsyslog, amazon-ec2, rsyslogd

I am using AWS Elasticbeanstalk to run my java web application. In EC2 node under /etc/rsyslog.d/web.conf

```
 if $programname  == 'web' then {
  *.=warning;*.=err;*.=crit;*.=alert;*.=emerg /var/log/web.stderr.log
  *.=info;*.=notice /var/log/web.stdout.log
}
```

I get what is being done.
but I did not get where the $programname is set as `web`. if i want to create my own programname and redirect logs to different file, how to do it?

Comment: Typically, the program name is set when a program calls `openlog()`.

Comment: so , openlog is called by elasticbeankstalk? is there any reference on how to create new programname?